# Need single data from multiple similar DATA in database

Tags: sql

I want to find out the data in showing in multiple entries like this

```
5   296 19  7   887 DAAS    GAGO    {"password":""}     2017-06-24 13:33:15 2017-06-23 13:33:09 9   10  fuel        4   1   N125XP  DAAS    Requested
5   296 19  7   887 DAAS    GAGO    {"password":""}     2017-06-24 13:33:15 2017-06-23 13:33:09 9   10  fuel        4   1   N125XP  DAAS    Requested
```

I want to see this data once how to do it ?
I am using this Sql Statement to do so :

```
SELECT t1.trip_id, 
       t1.server_trip_id, 
       t1.aircraft_id,
       t2.flight_id,
       t3.server_fid,
       t3.dep,
       t3.dest,
       t3.service_provider,
       t3.flight_name,
       t3.sta,
       t3.std,
       t4.booking_id,
       t5.server_booking_id,
       t5.type,
       t5.trip_number,
       t5.company_id,
       t5.user_id,
       t5.aircraft_registration,
       t5.icao,
       t6.status
FROM trip t1 
    JOIN trip_flight t2 ON t2.trip_id = t1.trip_id
    JOIN flight t3 ON t3.fid = t2.flight_id
    JOIN trip_flight_booking t4 ON t4.flight_id = t2.flight_id
    JOIN booking t5 ON t5.booking_id = t4.booking_id OR t5.booking_id != t4.booking_id
    JOIN booking_status t6 ON t6.booking_id = t5.booking_id OR t6.booking_id != t5.booking_id
where t1.aircraft_id="19"
```

Comment: Try using `DISTINCT`, although, the better solution would be to try and understand why you're getting multiple records.

Comment: Because the Database which I am using was old and had multiple entries of similar status as u see above there in total of 1510 results I am getting with status of requested pending confirmed multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your joins are correct... this seems to match any row;

```
t5.booking_id = t4.booking_id OR t5.booking_id != t4.booking_id
```

as you have = or != with the same values....

That said, you can use DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.trip_id , t1.server_trip_id, t1.aircraft_id,
t2.flight_id,
t3.server_fid,t3.dep,t3.dest,t3.service_provider,t3.flight_name,t3.sta,t3.std,
t4.booking_id,
t5.server_booking_id,t5.type,t5.trip_number,t5.company_id,t5.user_id,t5.aircraft_registration,t5.icao,
t6.status
    FROM trip t1 
    JOIN trip_flight t2 ON t2.trip_id = t1.trip_id
    JOIN flight t3 ON t3.fid = t2.flight_id
    JOIN trip_flight_booking t4 ON t4.flight_id = t2.flight_id
    JOIN booking t5 ON t5.booking_id = t4.booking_id OR t5.booking_id != t4.booking_id
    JOIN booking_status t6 ON t6.booking_id = t5.booking_id OR t6.booking_id != t5.booking_id
    where t1.aircraft_id="19"
```

Comment: Removing the OR parts brought down my results to 83 but still have multiple entries

Comment: Such as : 5 296 19 7 887 DAAS GAGO {"password":""}  2017-06-24 13:33:15 2017-06-23 13:33:09 9 13 fuel  4 1 N125XP DAAS Pending

Comment: This above results 4 times before anyother status